# LotusScript search formula - how to get documents created only in the current month?

Tags: lotusscript, lotus-formula

I am trying to create a SELECT formula for my documents in my search view.
It looks like this:

```
SELECT (Form = "Calculation" & @Created > [09/26/2017])
```

Every month I need to get documents which were created in the current month each time.

So, in the place of [09/26/2017] I must to put a first day of the current month, almost find the solution but no there yet.

Can you please provide a small solution or advise for this? 
Thank you!

**Update:**

This is my last variant:

```
StartDate := @Today;
StartOfThisMonth := @Date(@Year(StartDate); @Month(StartDate); 1);
SELECT Form = "Sum_access_by_corporations" & @Created >= StartOfThisMonth;
```

But, as Karl-Henry Martinsson noticed, this is an incorrect solution and I will try to find other solution for this.
And I have opened this question again.

Comment: You said you almost found the solution, but you haven't shown us what you tried!  Please post your code so we can see what you tried. Also, tell us what happens when you test that code. Does it work in some cases but not others? Or does it never work? What exactly does it do?

Comment: Hello, Richard.
I have already found the working solution, I will update my question, thank you.

Comment: You should never use Today or Now in view selections.

Comment: Instead of editing your question, adding an answer inside the question and adding `SOLVED` in your title, you should simply [add an answer to your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Hi Alexey, please add your answer to the answer section, you can accept it too.

Comment: TT, thanks for edit, you are right, but now, after Karls's advise, I have opened the question again.

Comment: bummi, thanks, I have added my new update, but the question isn't closed yet, my past solution was incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please do not listen to CBlunt, @Today and @Now are killing server performance, as it makes the view index "dirty". It will never be indexed, and the index task will run constantly.

You should never use them in a view selection. The proper way to do it is to have a scheduled agent, which will update a field, indicating if the document should be included in the view or not.

Comment: Hi. I didn't know it. Can you please tell more about the index issue or give some doc link to this and why is it happening? I am trying to figure out what will be the better solution to me. You are talking about the "dirty view index" for the current view performance or about the total performance of the server?

Comment: There are many references to this.  http://www.nsftools.com/tips/PerfTips.htm#databasetipsviews  
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/bpmpblog.nsf/dx/today-in-a-view?opendocument&comments  
http://www.breakingpar.com/bkp/home.nsf/0/87256B280015193F87256DA400496CF2  
And many more...

Comment: Thanks! It's really helped!